Mixture of factor analyzers: Correct expression for likelihood function?
I'm reading these notes about mixtures of factor analyzers, where the following generative model is described:

The conditional distribution of the data $x$ is stated (in Sec 3, eqn 9) as:
$$
P(x \mid z, \omega_j) = \mathcal{N}(\mu_j+\Lambda_j z, \Psi)
$$
where $\omega_j$ denotes the index of the $j$'th factor analyser (or mixture component if we can call it that) and $z \mid \omega_j \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I)$.
My question is: Am I correct in saying that $x \mid \omega_j \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_j, \Lambda_j \Lambda_j^\top + \Psi)$? And if I want to find the mixture component that most likely generated $x$, I maximize the following function:
$$
L(\omega_j) = P(x \mid \omega_j) = \mathcal{N}(x ; \mu_j, \Lambda_j \Lambda_j^\top+ \Psi) 
$$
right?
If correct, why is it that $P(\omega_j)$ doesn't matter in this likelihood function?
This expression looks a lot like posterior inference in Gaussian mixture models, i.e. finding the "responsibilities" of each cluster for the given data. Except of course, in this case, the covariance matrix has a sparse structure and I'm seeking a maximum likelihood estimator (I think?).
